# Does the 'through' argument in ManyToManyField in Django includes all fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does the 'through' argument in ManyToManyField in Django includes all fields in the related tables? For example will Group contain all Person and Membership fileds? And also how many levels deep can 'through' relationships can be?

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to make sense. Include all fields where?

Comment: What ever doubts you have can easily be cleared up by simply creating a few objects and inspecting their properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you use a through field the associated models' fields are all accessible from the related table. Levels can be deep as you can but it gets complicated better just to create separate tables.